# How to sort the post to a specific category

Tags: posts, categories

I want to make a list of posts in a particular category, how do I do this?

Please give a simple example that is easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_query()` is good option to show list of post in wordpress. If you want to show post of certain category then it can be done by using `category's ID` Or by `Category's slug`.

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',  //Specyfying post type
    'cat'=> 1,    //Selecting post category by ID to show
    'posts_per_page' => 10,  //No. of posts to show     
    'paged' => $paged       //For pagination
);
```

In above code I am showing category whose ID is 1 ('cat'=> 1,). 
If you want to show multiple categories then use code like this

```
'cat'=> '1,4,6',
```

In above code 1,4 and 6 are ID of different catogories.
If you want to leave any category then add minus in front of ID like this

```
'cat'=> -5,
```

If you want to call category by `slug` instead of `ID` then show it like this

```
'cat'=> 'type_slug_here',
```

After specifying array we will use `wp_query()` and `while loop` to show list of posts.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    //To show Title of post
    the_title();            
    /*****     Thumbnail     ******/
the_post_thumbnail(
array(120, 90),   //Width and height of featured image
    array(

    'class' => 'thumbnail',   //class to apply css properties
    'alt' => 'post thumbnail', //Alternate text if there is no image to show
    'title' => 'my custom title' //Title to specify
)
);
/*******     Thumbnail Ends   ********/

//Show description of post  
 the_content(__('Continue Reading'));
endwhile;
```

For more/brief detail [read this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). This article describes all detail about listing post But if you want to read only about showing one catogory right now then find heading with name `"Category Parameters"`.

> How to find Category ID

In case if you don't know `"how to find ID"`.
Go to `Dashboard -> Post -> Catagories`. There you will see all available categories (you can also create more categories there). You can find category ID by 
1. Hover on category name then 4 option will appear. Click on edit option, In edit page you can see ID in url.
2 Or simply hover in catogory then hover on `edit` option, By hovering on `edit` option you will see url at bottom left side of page. You can see ID there.